# Quantum counting statistics for fermions

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions

A system of two identical particles which ay occupy any of three energy levels: $$ε_n=nε$$  $n=0,1,2$

The lowest energy state, $ε=0$ is doubly degenerate.

The system is in thermal equilibrium at temperature $T$.

If the two particles obey Fermi-Dirac statistics. Then the partition function are given by:

$$Z_{2,f}=1+ 2 exp(-\frac{ε}{k_{B}T})+2 exp(-\frac{2ε}{k_{B}T}) + exp(-\frac{3ε}{k_{B}T}) $$

From my notes i have the Quantum counting statistics as $$\Omega_f=\sum_i{\frac{g_{i}!}{n_{i}!(g_{i}-n_{i})!}}$$

I am trying to releate the Quantum counting statistics to the above situation. What does Quantum counting statistics give for the above question.

Diagram of the above:

> [image: Blockquote]